# Apache config, to consume an HTTP request and return empty 200 OK

Tags: apache

Our web application is receiving HTTP requests to a particular path from a monitoring system we don't control. We would like to ignore those requests, and just return an empty 200 OK.

Is it possible to do this using only Apache config? (i.e. without having to create an additional empty file on the disk)

We don't want to alter our application, if possible, because this monitoring request is more to do with the deployment landscape, and not really to do with the application.

We are using Apache 2.2.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is match the request, whatever it's form, being it a specific source ip, the method of request, the request itself and just redirect it to a landing page that you know gives a 200, or a simple txt file.

Methods of doing it, most common one would be Redirect/RedirectMatch if the request is specific and you want to redirect it, of mod_rewrite if you have to match something more complicated and want to yield a straight "200 OK"

Here is a example.Let's say it is a specific IP:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.144\.45$
RewriteRule ^ /we-re-fine.txt [L]
```

Sidenote: If you had provided a pattern or something more specific to identify your exact case I could have been more specific.

Comment: Is it possible to just return an empty 200 OK request without having to have an additional file on the disk? Sorry for not being clearer, I have updated my question to clarify.

Comment: Not that I can think of right now, well, against my better judgment I guess you could try something ugly like `RewriteRule ^ - [R=200,L]` instead of the rewriterule I added, that will return a 200 without a file or anything, but it is ugly. If you really don't want to touch your application there is not need to add a file in it or anything, just add an Alias to another directory, give access to it, and create a landing page there.